# Filtered "Hot questions" in the StackExchange box

Tags: feature-request

The Hot Questions item in the StackExchange box could show questions from my sites. 
I filtered the StackEchange main page to see just the questions from the sites I want to see and I would expect to see those questions there.

Comment: I'd prefer that too... since, if I were interested in these sites, I'd be subscribed.  And I'm not.